# IOS detect if another textfield was clicked on End On Exit event

Tags: ios, animation, uitextfield

I am trying to detect if certain textfield has been clicked in an `End On Exit` event for the current selected `TextField`.
Let me show you instead of trying to explain:

```
- (IBAction)txtUsernameEdit:(id)sender {
    CGRect loginButton = btnLogin.frame;
    CGRect registerButton = btnRegister.frame;
    loginButton.origin.x = 19;
    loginButton.origin.y = 175;
    registerButton.origin.x = 189;
    registerButton.origin.y = 175;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];  
    btnLogin.frame = loginButton;
    btnRegister.frame = registerButton;    
}

- (IBAction)txtUsernameEndExit:(id)sender {
    if (!txtPassword.isTouchInside) {
    CGRect loginButton = btnLogin.frame;
    CGRect registerButton = btnRegister.frame;
    loginButton.origin.x = 19;
    loginButton.origin.y = 308;
    registerButton.origin.x = 189;
    registerButton.origin.y = 308;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];    
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    btnLogin.frame = loginButton;
    btnRegister.frame = registerButton;
    }
}

- (IBAction)txtPasswordEdit:(id)sender {
    CGRect loginButton = btnLogin.frame;
    CGRect registerButton = btnRegister.frame;
    loginButton.origin.x = 19;
    loginButton.origin.y = 175;
    registerButton.origin.x = 189;
    registerButton.origin.y = 175;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context    :nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];    
    btnLogin.frame = loginButton;
    btnRegister.frame = registerButton;
}

- (IBAction)txtPasswordEndExit:(id)sender {
    if (!txtPassword.isHighlighted) {
    CGRect loginButton = btnLogin.frame;
    CGRect registerButton = btnRegister.frame;
    loginButton.origin.x = 19;
    loginButton.origin.y = 308;
    registerButton.origin.x = 189;
    registerButton.origin.y = 308;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    btnLogin.frame = loginButton;
    btnRegister.frame = registerButton;
    }
}
```

So I have two textfields `txtUsername` and `txtPassword`.
the functions `txtUsernameEndExit` and `txtPasswordEndExit` are fired when the user clicked on the opposite textfield or the done key on the keyboard. How can I find out in those functions if the user dit actually click there?

In the if-clause I tried the following attributes and methods:
 - isFirstResponder
 - isTouchInside
 - isEditing
 - isHighlighted

But I guess that none of these attributes have been changed if the End On Exit function hasn't been fired yet.

What would be the appropriate approach?

**EDIT - DIFFERENT APPROACH**
So, recently I figured that I could also observer the keyboard's show or hide.
I have autolayout enabled for my view and there are only two textfields and two buttons on it. As soon as I tap a textfield, the buttons come up as the animation describes and the go down again (apparently autoreverse does this) but if I tap a textfield and afterwards tap another textfield the keyboard doesn't go down but the buttons do.
Here's all the code I used to animate this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif{
    CGRect loginButton = btnLogin.frame;
    CGRect registerButton = btnRegister.frame;
    loginButton.origin.x = 19;
    loginButton.origin.y = 175;
    registerButton.origin.x = 189;
    registerButton.origin.y = 175;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    btnLogin.frame = loginButton;
    btnRegister.frame = registerButton;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use UITextFieldDelegate methods:

- textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
- textFieldDidBeginEditing:
- textFieldShouldEndEditing:
- textFieldDidEndEditing:

Comment: Well, I've been working on ios development only a few days ago. I don't know anything about xcode :( I'll google, that, thanks

Comment: Ah, ok. This tutorial will help you then: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate/

Comment: @RobbieVercammen This has nothing to do with Xcode. These are features of the standard iOS framework (Cocoa-touch). Look at the reference docs for `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just recently I figured that I could also observe the keyboard's hide and show but the same problem remails. I'll update my question